# Proxy_pass 127.0.0.1 in nginx does not work

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I install nginx as a reverse proxy. If I use:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81
```

it does not work. But if I use:

```
proxy_pass http://domain.com:81
```

it works. And I can use browser to access to `http://domain.com:81` and `http://ip:81`

Could anyone explain for me?

Comment: What happens if you "telnet 127.0.0.1 81"? It should give you a connected message.

Comment: In fact, my port I want is 8080 and this is result
telnet: 127.0.0.1:8080: Name or service not known
127.0.0.1:8080: Unknown host

Comment: Define "does not work". Do you get an error? Do you get the wrong answer from the server? Do you get nothing at all?

Answer (score 0):

The telnet command I gave shouldn't have a colon. It should be "telnet 127.0.0.1 8080". It it doesn't work then I would guess whatever web server you're using isn't being bound to 127.0.0.1 and/or port 8080.

Comment: "telnet 127.0.0.1 8080" command worked. Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'. So what's the problem here. I already stuck

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find reason why it doesn't work, but what if you try like this:

proxy_pass http://localhost:81